# How much of a difference does the valve make on water pressure when picking out a new shower faucet?

Tags: shower, faucet, water-pressure

I'm remodeling my master shower and will replace my old faucet with a new one (valve included in the new package). I want as much water pressure as possible. Should I only look at the gpm on the shower head, or do different valves have different water pressure, too?

Comment: Are you currently having water flow (more likely than pressure) issues?  If so, the chances are good that you will not have any better luck with a new faucet than with the old one.  As long as you're going through the expense of a remodel, why not fix the underlying issues at the same time?

Comment: a good shower has almost nothing to do with pressure, assuming we're talking about for washing human bodies. It's all about flow, aka GPM. The fastest working shower I've used was a diverted stream of mountain runoff in an open trough, which has basically no pressure, but had 100s of GPM; rinses your hair in a second or two. Any increase of pressure will come at the cost of reduced flow.